# Como criar uma sequencia de leitura em um campo da Select no Banco de Dados Oracle?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, tabela-banco-de-dados, oracle12c

Estou com um problema no meu código gostaria de uma ajuda com um trecho do meu código.
a linha ITE.SEQUENCIA não queria deixar o número 1 fixo, por pode ser que um item seja excluído e inicia com o próximo número, seria possível criar uma sequencia dentro do código no banco de dados Oracle?

Obrigado a todos.

Ex: Código

```
     (SELECT MAX(CAB2.VLRNOTA)
    FROM TGFCAB CAB2, TGFDIN DIN
        WHERE ITE.NUNOTA = CAB2.NUNOTA
        AND CAB2.STATUSNOTA = 'L'
        AND ITE.SEQUENCIA = 1 -- QUERIA QUE O ITE.SEQUENCIA PEGASSE SEMPRE O PRIMEIRO NUMERO DISPONÍVEL, POIS NÃO COMEÇARIA SEMPRE COM NUMERO 1
        AND ITE.NUNOTA = DIN.NUNOTA
        AND ITE.SEQUENCIA = DIN.SEQUENCIA) AS VALOR_DA_NOTA
```

Comment: Sua descrição do problema está bastante confusa mas, chutando, creio que um subselect pegando o menor valor do campo SEQUENCIA, do que creio ser a tabela ITE não listada, possa ajuda-lo.

Comment: Desculpa a transcrição é que é um código bastante extenso, é uma ITE sim, com sequencia, quando começa uma venda, e se cancela 1 item, ele elimina a sequencia 1, e vai para 2, se exclui uma segunda sequencia vai para 2 e assim sucessivamente. Queria vincular por exemplo VALOR tabela em apenas um campo da sequencia, para não duplicar em um relatório. Não sei se ficou mais confuso mais vou postar o código inteiro.

https://pastebin.com/AWeq4dyF

Answer (score 0):

Oracle tem a funcionalidade de sequencias. Ver o link em baixo para mais detalhes.
Sumariamente, para criar a sequência:

```
 CREATE SEQUENCE customers_seq
   START WITH     1000
   INCREMENT BY   1
   NOCACHE
   NOCYCLE;
```

Mas, pela descrição que faz, não se percebe o cenário em que a sequência seria usada e não é claro que uma sequência seja a melhor opção.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_6015.htm#SQLRF01314